# Google App Engine Error: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'require'

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine

I'm doing a tutorial on Google App Engine and I"m getting this error:

```
ERROR    2016-08-27 17:41:18,545 webapp2.py:1552] __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'require'
```

And I don't know what it's asking for or what it means. Please advise. Thanks.

This happens when I call:

Controller:

```
json_response = Users.add_new_user(name, email, password)
```

Model:

```
class Users(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    email = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    password = db.StringProperty(require = True)
    confirmation_code = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    confirmed_email = db.BooleanProperty(default = False)

    @classmethod
    def check_if_exists(cls, email):
        return cls.query(cls.email == email).get()

    @classmethod
    def add_new_user(cls, name, email, password):
        user = cls.check_if_exists(email)

        if not user:
            random_bytes = urandom(64)
            salt = b64encode(random_bytes).decode('utf-8')
            hashed_password = salt + sha256(salt + password).hexdigest()

            confirmation_code = str(uuid.uuid4().get_hex())

            new_user_key = cls(
                name=name,
                email=email,
                password=hashed_password,
                confirmation_code=confirmation_code
            ).put()

            print(new_user_key)


            return {
                'created': True,
                'user_id': new_user_key.id(),
                'confirmation_code':confirmation_code
            }

        else:
            return {
                'created': False,
                'title': 'This email is already in use',
                'message': 'Please log in if this is your email account. '
            }
```

Comment: please add the stack trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo: `require` instead of `required` here:

```
    password = db.StringProperty(require = True)
```

Comment: The log is pretty good.  A quick search for `require` as described in the error is going to show you the line.